# what do you call a person who speaks in opposites; not just being contrary or being a contrarian

Tags: single-word-requests

I am reading G.K. Chesterton's Heretics.
It appears to me that he presents his ideas in opposing view points in the same sentence.
It is almost like he is of the opinion that his opinions are the only truths.

Comment: So each sentence is a ... paradox?

Comment: Welcome. Can you give an example of such a sentence? Also a link to the online text would help. Thanks.

Comment: Your last sentence is clear: he thinks that he knows the absolute truth. The sentence before is then confusing: it seems that it refers to a discussion of ideas. May you clarify ?

Comment: I agree with the assessment of paradox. After reading a few pages of _Heretics_, it's clear that Chesterton is using paradox, which I think you could get away with as calling a technique that is a part of the larger, broader style of using dialectical language, based on the response provided by Drew. But @mohsain_essa, the use of paradox or dialectical language does not insinuate that one holds himself superior to others. I find that to be purely coincidental in this case.

Comment: In reading the responses I find 'arbitrarystringofletter' to have offered the clearest answer. I appreciate your response very much. I do not know if there is a noun that identify a person who speaks in paradoxes. Also so everyone knows I am not a literary person nor a linguist. I just love to read and my bend is toward being a skeptic. Thank you again for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

- *Dialectical*: Of or pertaining to dialectic.
- *Dialectic*:

  1. Any formal system of reasoning that arrives at the truth by the exchange of logical arguments
  2. A contradiction of ideas that serves as the determining factor in their interaction
     "this situation created the inner dialectic of American history"

  -- [WordWeb on line](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=dialectical)